# webdriver getText() issue with large amount of values

Tags: webdriver, gettext

I'll try to explain what I see in a few words.

I use webdriver + testNG on a win7 machine.

I have a table and get a reference to it. When I try to get all the text contained in such table, if it's empty (only header) then there are no problems .

But, if there are more rows, the table.getText() is not working properly and the result is:

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding.
>
> You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
>
> Script: file:///C:/Users/VM-AUT~1/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous2085126608473413720webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:6047

I have tried increasing the timeout but the result is the same. If I decide to continue, getText() returns me all the values and the script continues.

This is a very short description but I don't want to be boring, but if more details are needed just let me know.

Comment: What exact code are you using? Against what browser? What version of Selenium? Against what table (show the HTML)?

Comment: How large is the table? A few rows (e.g. 1-10), or many many rows of data?

Answer (score 0):

A few more infos:

If the table has +-5 records it works fine.

There is a problem if it has +-20 records per page (it's possible to switch between pages)

The problem persists with FF 23 ( looks fine with chrome & IE)  but didnt check with previous FF versions

I use java + testNG + selenium grid but have the same problem on my local machine as well

If I select  CONTINUE at the "A script on this page may be busy....." message, gettext()returns me the correct values I use the selenium 2.33

Table looks like:

driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='smslog_outer_table']")).getText()

```
<table id="smslog_outer_table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<table class="table table-condensed" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
<tr class="gwtutility-table-tr-head">
<tr class="delivered">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<div class="gwt-Label">043081410085553301</div>
</td>
<td class="log_date_time" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="" colspan="1">
<td class="log_status" colspan="1">
<td class="log_date_time" colspan="1">
<td class="log_message" colspan="1">
</tr>
<tr class="delivered">
<tr class="delivered">
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```